# can i obtain nonce in native ios app using square SDK or some other way

Tags: square, square-connect

I am new to Square API!!
My question is.

> Can we generate **nonce** directly on my iOS native app without opening Square Register App? Just like on website..

What i want is to use my back-end code to handle the transactions request. OR suggest me some good solution. Only i want to handle transactions at back-end services

Answer (score 0):

Sure! 
If you can use a web view in your mobile application, you can implement the Square form just like on a website. There is **not** a way to generate card nonces directly.

Comment: That mean we can not anyway use SDK for this purpose. i was hoping this solution :) thanks